# Undefined method render_to_string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a gem that contains a method called get_component that is supposed to render the card called and it's specific data. I also have a call in a separate host app that makes the call to the gem method. I'm trying to make a simple integration but rails seems to think that the method doesn't exist, which is confusing because `ApplicationController` inherits from `ActionController::Base`. I've tried to manually make an object of the ActionController class.

```
ac = ActionController::Base.new()
ac.render_to_string()
```

and also calling ApplicationController again:

```
ApplicationController.new.render_to_string
```

Which doesn't particularly make sense but was worth testing. Both times i still end up with:

```
undefined method `render_to_string' for Pugin::ApplicationController:Class
```

I'm a little stumped, Does it not recognise ActionController::Base in the controller or is there something fundamentally wrong with how I'm trying to call the method?

Person File

```
=> PUGIN.get_component('modules/card', { \
    title: defined?(person.display_name) ? link_to(person.display_name, person_path(person.id)) : "No Information", \
    house: defined?(person.houses.first.id) ? person.houses.first.id : "Lord", \
    image: [{ src: "http://wraggelabs.com/static/images/default_avatar-2.gif", \
              alt: person.display_name \
           }], \
    details: [{ description: defined?(person.constituencies.first.id) ? link_to(person.constituencies.first.name, constituencies_path(person.constituencies.first.id)) : "No Information"}, \
             { description: defined?(person.houses.first.id) ? link_to(person.houses.first.id, houses_path(person.houses.first.id)) : "No Information"}, \
             { description: defined?(person.parties.first.id) ? link_to(person.parties.first.name, houses_path(person.parties.first.id)) : "No Information"}] \
   })
```

PUGIN gem controller

```
module Pugin
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    def self.get_component(component_name, properties = {})
      #properties.each |property| do
        #render :partial => "layouts/pugin/#{component_name}", locals: {properties: property}
        render_to_string("layouts/pugin/_#{component_name}", :formats => [:html])
      #end
    end

  end
end
```

NOTE: I'm aware that the implementation of render_to_string is probably wrong and will break at the moment. But the problem at hand is just trying to get the method to be recognised.

Comment: Why is `get_component` a class method in this controller?  `render_to_string` is a `protected` instance method from ActionController and  you're calling it from a class method which might be the issue.